# How to reference model from controller (MVC) or vice versa without using statics. JavaFX 8

Tags: javafx

I'm sure this is fairly simple and I am misunderstanding something. I have a controller class linked to an FXML(view). The controller does not contain any statics, yet when I try and reference the model like this:

```
 @FXML
 public void goToConvert(MouseEvent event){ 
     myController.setScreen(GameModel.CONVERT_SCREEN); 
     GameModel.CONVERTB = true;
     GameModel.PLAYB = false;
     GameModel.COMPAREB = false;
     GameModel.SETTINGSB = false;
     GameModel.HELPB = false;
     GameModel.ProcessSreeenSwitch();
```

GameModel is my model
CONVERTB is a public boolean
ProcessScreeenSwitch() is a public void

Without taking any measures to include an object reference to GameModel in the controller, every line using GameModel creates the common error:

```
non-static variable CONVERTB cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Even though there are no statics in the controller whatsoever. I don't understand why the current context is static. I have tried declaring GameModel as an object above e.g (in the same place as ScreensController myController is declared in the code at the bottom)

```
 GameModel GameModel = new GameModel();
```

or

```
 GameModel GameModel;
```

These measures stop the static error but create a NullPointerException when they are called. For example, if goToConvert is called the NullPointerException is at the line:

```
GameModel.CONVERTB = true;
```

How can I make the current context non-static to change the values in the GameModel from the controller.

Cheers

Lucio

```
Controller Class:
    package aimdot;

import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PlayScreenController implements Initializable, 
                                            ControlledScreen { 

     ScreensController myController; 
     //final static Image MOUSECURSOR = new Image (PlayScreenController.class.getResource("MouseCursor").toString());
     //final static Image MOUSECURSOR_IMAGE = new Image (PlayScreenController.class.getResource("MouseCursor").toString());
    // final static Image MOUSECURSOR_IMAGE = new Image (PlayScreenController.class.getResource("MouseCursor").toString());
    @FXML
    private ImageView imageView;
     @FXML
    private ImageView MouseCursor;
      @FXML
    private ImageView RectangleMouseHolder;
       @FXML
    private ImageView Target3Rings;
        @FXML
    private Label PLAYBUTTON;


     @Override
     public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {


            } 


     public void setScreenParent(ScreensController screenParent){ 
        myController = screenParent; 
     }   

     @FXML 
     private void PLAYBUTTONPressed(MouseEvent event){ 
     PLAYBUTTON.setTranslateX(-400);
     GameModel.AnimationTargetStart();
     PLAYPHASE();
   } 
    @FXML
    public void TargetMissed(ActionEvent event){ 


   }


     @FXML
    public void goToPlay(MouseEvent event){ 
     myController.setScreen(GameModel.PLAY_SCREEN); 
     GameModel.CONVERTB = false;
     GameModel.PLAYB = true;
     GameModel.COMPAREB = false;
     GameModel.SETTINGSB = false;
     GameModel.HELPB = false;
     GameModel.ProcessSreeenSwitch();
   } 
     @FXML 
     private void goToMain(ActionEvent event){ 
     myController.setScreen(GameModel.MAIN_MENU); 
     GameModel.CONVERTB = false;
     GameModel.PLAYB = false;
     GameModel.COMPAREB = false;
     GameModel.SETTINGSB = false;
     GameModel.HELPB = false;
     GameModel.ProcessSreeenSwitch();
   } 


    @FXML
    public void goToConvert(MouseEvent event){ 
     myController.setScreen(GameModel.CONVERT_SCREEN); 
     GameModel.CONVERTB = true;
     GameModel.PLAYB = false;
     GameModel.COMPAREB = false;
     GameModel.SETTINGSB = false;
     GameModel.HELPB = false;
     GameModel.ProcessSreeenSwitch();
   } 

    @FXML
    public void goToCompare(MouseEvent event){ 
     myController.setScreen(GameModel.COMPARE_SCREEN); 
     GameModel.CONVERTB = false;
     GameModel.PLAYB = false;
     GameModel.COMPAREB = true;
     GameModel.SETTINGSB = false;
     GameModel.HELPB = false;
     GameModel.ProcessSreeenSwitch();
   } 

   @FXML
    public void goToSettings(MouseEvent event){ 
     myController.setScreen(GameModel.SETTINGS_SCREEN);
     GameModel.CONVERTB = false;
     GameModel.PLAYB = false;
     GameModel.COMPAREB = false;
     GameModel.SETTINGSB = true;
     GameModel.HELPB = false;
     GameModel.ProcessSreeenSwitch();
   }        

   @FXML
    public void goToHelp(MouseEvent event){ 
     myController.setScreen(GameModel.HELP_SCREEN); 
     GameModel.CONVERTB = false;
     GameModel.PLAYB = false;
     GameModel.COMPAREB = false;
     GameModel.SETTINGSB = false;
     GameModel.HELPB = true;
     GameModel.ProcessSreeenSwitch();
   }  

    @FXML
    public void MouseLocation(MouseEvent event){ 

   }
    @FXML
    public void RestartButton(MouseEvent event){ 

       GameModel.RestartRound();

   }




 public void PLAYPHASE(){
     boolean targetSpawned = false;

     GameModel.playPhase = true;


     long gameStartMS = System.currentTimeMillis();
     long gameStartS = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(gameStartMS);


     }


 }
```

EDITED for addition steps tried.

tried using

```
 GameModel Model = new GameModel();
```

in each controller, and eliminating use of GameModel fromt he controller but it didn't work. It still creates a null pointer exception at

```
Model.ProcessSreeenSwitch();
```

In GameModel class:

```
public void ProcessSreeenSwitch(){
        System.out.print("PlayB: "+PLAYB);
        if (PLAYB == false){
            target.setVisible(false);
            PlayLabel.setVisible(false);
            PutMouseMiddle.setVisible(false);
            hitCountG.setVisible(false);
            missCountG.setVisible(false);
            rectangleMouseBoxG.setVisible(false);
           RestartPlayButton.setVisible(false);
           PlayTimer.setVisible(false);
           PlayTimerText.setVisible(false);
        }
        if (PLAYB == true){
            target.setVisible(true);
            PlayLabel.setVisible(true);
            PutMouseMiddle.setVisible(true);
            hitCountG.setVisible(true);
            missCountG.setVisible(true);
           rectangleMouseBoxG.setVisible(true);
           RestartPlayButton.setVisible(true);
           PlayTimer.setVisible(true);
           PlayTimerText.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Edited for stack trace

```
   stack trace:     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.java
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not what it's saying.

> non-static variable CONVERTB cannot be referenced from a static
>   context

That means this -> `GameModel.CONVERTB`.

You're trying to reference it from a static (`GameModel`) context. The variable isn't static!

A fix, other than actually making the variable static and doing what you're doing, would be to instantiate a GameModel and access it that way. Know that this is a *new* GameModel and probably not the one you need. The way that's done is...

```
GameModel model = new GameModel(); 
model.CONVERTB ...;
```

Note this isn't the proper naming convention for fields and gives the impression it's `final` or constant.

If you have a single GameModel you want to operate on, which is likely, you'll have to have a game model instance in the controller which you can access.

In addition, I wouldn't declare a reference with caps like its class name, as you can see it adds confusion where statics are involved.

Comment: At the end of the question, I was trying to say that I have tried putting a GameModel reference in the controllers. It doesn't work and just creates another null pointer exception, this was after removing all the statics from the program.

Comment: @LucioMaximo - In your edit you say there's a NPE on the call to a specific method but what about where you access `CONVERTB` (a public boolean). They can't be null nor can the reference you instantiated. If you're getting an NPE through a method call, check the stack trace and see where inside that method the exception is being called from. It's not because the object you just created is null.

Comment: Edited and put in the stack trace, my GameModel start method doesn't even begin before the NPE occurs.

Comment: @Lucio, I think it's pretty safe to say the statics issue was corrected and now you have another problem. Both are compile time errors so this one probably never got a chance to report until now. I think you either have a new post altogether or some needed code missing from this one. I'm guessing a new one. This post is already on the verge of becoming a dynamic problem chaser where one thing gets fixed only to expose another. These should be separate ideally so the answers match the question. If you are not using reflection in your code then I guess it must be something with the launch.